# How to get Pitch class values in Hz from librosa chroma_stft

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing, librosa

I use Librosa library to calculate chroma from audio signal.

```
chroma = librosa.feature.chroma_stft(y=audiosignal, sr=44100, window=window, n_fft=8192, hop_length=3276)
```

**I would like to know how to find the pitch class value in Hz?** because the Librosa library return chromagram value with `shape=(n_chroma, t)`, but I want to get "frequency" and "time" information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Hz, maybe you're looking for [librosa.feature.stft](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.stft.html) which returns a frequency in Hz instead of a pitch class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).